# spring boot data redis integrated with spring data jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-aop, spring-data-redis

I am using spring boot `1.5.2.RELEASE` and spring data redis and spring data jpa.

1. I want to query data from redis first
2. if data cannot foud from redis, then from mysql.

something like this:

**get method**

```
Object cacheValue = cache.get("key");
if(null != cacheValue){
    return cacheValue;
} else {
    Object dbValue = getFromInDb("key");
    cache.set("key", value);
    return dbValue;
}
```

delete method

```
Object cacheValue = cache.get("key");
if(null != cacheValue){
    cache.delete("key");
    db.deleteByKey("key")
} else {
    db.deleteByKey("key")
}
```

I am now using spring aop I can finish the work. I wonder if I use spring data redis repository can do the same thing and how ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `@Cacheable` and `@CacheDelete` annotations to your service? Spring Data Redis comes with a Cache implementation that might leverage your approach.

Comment: do you have some simple demo? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data Redis should be able to meet your requirements. My advice would be to get the autoconfigured in memory caching to work using `@Cacheable` and other annotations on your methods. Once working plug in Redis by including Redis in your dependencies. You may run into issues with serialization, but this is a different issue. 
[Spring Boot Caching Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/caching/). It really is that simple to use the in memory cache. You can add some print statements in your methods to verify when they run and when the result is cached.
[More useful spring boot cache info](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-caching.html)